# Cognito - does cognito automatically store the tokens locally?

Tags: security, local-storage, amazon-cognito

i'm new to cognito. i'm using user pools and call userPool.getCurrentUser() to get the current user and then getSession() to get the idToken, accessToken and refreshToken - as i understand it these are stored automatatically in the local storage by cognito (as confirmed by being able to access these tokens even if there is no internet connection).

i'd appreciate some clarification with the following 3 questions:

question 1) i presume these tokens were stored by cognito when the user last was authenticated (so they will expire as per their defaults)?

question 2) the documentation states: "We strongly recommended that you secure all three tokens in transit and storage in the context of your application." - why should we store them when cognito is already storing them locally?

question 3) if cognito is storing the tokens locally, do we have to do anything to ensure that they are stored securely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, they were stored by Cognito when the last user authenticated and yes, they will expire based on the defaults or by configuration for the refresh token.

2) It's just that if someone gets your valid access token they have access to your account. So I would assume it's just a security recommendation on how to handle the tokens.

3) You now have the option to pass your own storage to the Cognito objects depending on your application's needs so you don't need to use local storage at all.

Comment: thanks for answering my questions Ionut. regarding question 2) yes, i understand why we need to secure the tokens but what i was meaning is, why should we save them when cognito is already saving them? regarding question 3) i don't understand what you mean by "You now have the option to pass your own storage to the Cognito objects" - what i was wanting to know is, cognito is saving the tokens to local storage - so do i have to do anything to secure them or are they secure (i.e cognito has secured them)?

Comment: okay,got some clarity on this. 1) cognito saves the tokens in local storage 2) there is much debate as to whether this is safe. some say it is and other say it is not. some suggest rather saving in a cookie.consensus seems to be that if your site is hacked, specifically by XSS, then it is likely that tokens stored in cookies will also be compromised 3) you can save the tokens in your own storage (see AWS Amplify Auth docs)

Comment: @CliveSargeant what did you end up doing?